# How to use - (NSString *)encodeWrappedBase64ForData in swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I need encode a video in NSData type with `- (NSString *)encodeWrappedBase64ForData{}` from this class
https://github.com/kailoa/iphone-smtp/blob/master/Classes/NSData%2BBase64Additions.m

IN Objective C I call this like:

```
  [videoPath encodeWrappedBase64ForData]
  NSDictionary * vcfPart3 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"video/quicktime;\r\n\tx-unix-mode=0644;\r\n\tname=\"video.mp4\"",kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,
                           @"attachment;\r\n\tfilename=\"video.mp4\"",kSKPSMTPPartContentDispositionKey, [videoPath encodeWrappedBase64ForData], kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey, @"base64", kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey, nil];
```

But in Swift, I can't import the class `NSData+Base64Additions`

But I don't know how can I call this in Swift. How can I call this from swift?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add the class files to your project (for this call, you will need only *NSData+Base64Additions.h*, *NSData+Base64Additions.m*, *Base64Transcoder.h*, and *Base64Transcoder.m*).
2. Xcode will ask if you want a bridging header, if you don't already have one. You do!
3. In the bridging header, import *NSData+Base64Additions.h*, so that Swift can see the imported files:

   ```
   #import "NSData+Base64Additions.h"
   ```

Done! Now you can call NSData methods defined in that category:

```
let s = d.encodeWrappedBase64ForData()
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably can import the `NSData+Base64Additions` library with judicious use of the bridging headers, but it's not necessary. iOS has its own native base-64 routines, e.g.

```
let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: path)
let base64String = data.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(nil)
```